# /etc/hosts - How can I point to a certain directory in my local intranet?

Tags: linux, redirect, hosts

I need to point `admin.company.com` to `192.168.2.100/admin`

How can I do that?

Comment: You should tell us the protocol using to access this folder! HTTP, samba share, etc..

Comment: http [... 15 char]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this through etc hosts.  You are mixing up 2 different protocols here, http and dns.  /etc/hosts will help you redirect admin.company.com to 192.168.2.100, but you need to the redirection to /admin on the web server.

If you are using apache you want to likely used named virtual hosts

```
...
Port 80
ServerName server.domain.tld

NameVirtualHost 111.22.33.44 

<VirtualHost 111.22.33.44>
DocumentRoot /www/domain
ServerName www.domain.tld
...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 111.22.33.44>
DocumentRoot /www/subdomain
ServerName www.sub.domain.tld
...
</VirtualHost>
```

This article outlines this: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/vhosts/examples.html

Comment: Hmm.. how can I do this then? I want admin.local.com pointing to one directory, and a staff.local.com pointing to another?

Comment: added to my entry - thats for apache let me know if you are using IIS on the webserver.  Also keep in mind that debian/ubuntu/cent also sometimes use their own configuration files.  More information on what your setup is will help advise on how to help